# iTerm2 - How to show alternate screen in iTerm2?

Tags: macos, iterm, keybindings

In Terminal.app, there is a shortcut to **Show Alternate Screen**:

<kbd>Shift</kbd>  +  <kbd>Command</kbd>  +  <kbd>↓</kbd>

Is there a shortcut to do the same thing in iTerm2? If no, is there a way to assign one? How?

Comment: man screen tells you how to turn on alternate screen mode. It is related to the variable altscreen on|off.  I don't know how to set this on.

Comment: i think the screen command with no options dumps you into a window in alternate mode.

Comment: "Show Alternate Screen"??? There is no such thing in any of the menus of iTerm2.  Can you explain what you're talking about?  It was not explained in the answer either, or the feature request linked to.

Comment: In case others are confused, see https://terminalguide.namepad.de/mode/p47/

Comment: If you go to Preferences > Keys > Key Bindings then add a new key binding. In the resulting window, search for 'Alternate Screen' and then assign a key binding. I set mine to Control-Shift-h to match the typical binding for alternate screens in other terminal emulators like xterm.

Answer (score 4):

By searching the [one page documentation of iTerm2](https://www.iterm2.com/documentation-one-page.html) for each occurrence of the expression **alternate screen**, we can deduce that this feature is not yet implemented in iTerm2 3.2.0.

== EDIT ==

Here is a [feature request on the Gitlab repository of iterm2](https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/issues/6998).

== EDIT (2) ==

The feature has been implemented with commit 7b8d6a4b4. You can already test it in the nightly build in the Session > Terminal State menu.

According to George Nachman (the maintainer):

> There is no shortcut (I'm basically out of shortcuts) but you can always assign one in Prefs > Keys.

Thanks to him for this new feature!

Comment: There appears to be an alternate screen mode in iTerm2 based on this webpage on the iterm2 web page. https://www.iterm2.com/documentation-preferences.html. it mentions the alternate screen mode but I can't find where it tells how to enter that mode.